# CakePHP Pagination SQL Injection

Tags: cakephp, sql-injection, pagination

I'm working on a CakePHP (version 2.6.7) project. I have a search page where a user searches a term and the results are displayed using the CakePHP paginator like so:

```
$this->Paginator->settings['conditions']['Records.name like'] = '%'.$this->request->query['searched_term'].'%';
$this->set('results', $this->Paginator->paginate('Records'));
```

Does paginate protect from SQL injections? `$this->request->query['searched_term']` is entered by the user so it cannot be trusted and I can't find any information about if paginate prevents SQL injections.

I am aware of `Sanitize::clean()` but it is marked as depreciated. Should I use it anyway? If not, what should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the paginator is issuing `Model::find()` calls, so it's as safe as `find()` generally is.

And generally everything (except for expression objects) on the value side of a `field => value` style condition is going to be subject to automatic quoting/escaping, so what you are showing there is safe.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Retrieving Your Data > Complex Find Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions)**
- **[API > DboSource::expression()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-DboSource.html#_expression)**